# Tally approach to print days of next 30 years - why to add primary key constraint to tally?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, sql-server-2014, primary-key

This is the query I am using to print out all the days in the next 30 years.

```
SELECT TOP 11000 --number of days for 30 years
       IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS N
INTO #Tally
FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
     Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2

declare @endDate datetime = '2049-01-01'
       ,@tmpDate datetime = '2019-01-01'

select dateadd(day, t.N - 1, @tmpDate)
from #Tally t
where t.N - 1 <= DATEDIFF(day, @tmpDate, @endDate)
```

It is working well. However, I am suggested by an SQL Expert to add those query below right under the first section where I create #Tally.

```
ALTER TABLE #Tally
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Tally_N 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N) WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
```

If I run `select * from #Tally` the "ALTER" query above, there is no change in the result table.

I wonder what the reason is that I should to add the ALTER query (couldn't ask him)? What is the purpose of that? I see it is adding a primary key constraint but why to use `clustered(n)` and `fillfactor=100` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing any joins or utilising the PK (`N`) for any other purpose than returning the results as indicated?

Comment: @Martin no, just printing the dates for now. I'll need to use join tho in the future work.

Comment: I guess it was done to: a) make optimizer works better - it will know that column is unique and b) decrease storage used by this table

Comment: @Piotr how it decreases the storage, could u please briefly explain?

Comment: It doesn't decrease storage. If anything it increases it as it now needs to store non leaf pages

Comment: You should create the table with the CI up front rather than as a heap then CI. With the heap first If all you are doing with the tally table is that single query once and then the temp table is dropped as it goes out of scope then yes you don't need to add an index as the overhead of adding an index will be greater than the cost of the single query. How are you using this in practice? And if you do add the index you should change the predicate to `where t.N  <= DATEDIFF(day, @tmpDate, @endDate) + 1` so it is sargable

Comment: @MartinSmith: Correct, I should say is that adding the FILLFACTOR = 100 will prevent wasting space when creating index, it will still use more space than heap.

Comment: There is more to the DBMS state than what rows are in the tables. Also, PK/UNIQUE constraints & indexes are different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of the specified index, SQL Server would scan the entire table everytime you looked up a value. So, for example, if you ran the following....

```
 SELECT * FROM #Tally WHERE N = 858;
```

SQL Server would scan the entire table to get that one record, which isn't terribly efficent. Let's say you had 30 processes running queries just like that. You'd end up with all sorts of blocking problems.

If you added the specified index, that same query would find N without scanning the entire table and return a result. Lookups on the table would be efficient, and the schema you'd have created would support greater concurrency.

Now, for the query you provided...

```
select dateadd(day, t.N - 1, @tmpDate)
from #Tally t
where t.N - 1 <= DATEDIFF(day, @tmpDate, @endDate)
```

SQL Server will likely just do a table scan anyway. So, presence of a clustered index really doesn't give you a ton of bang for your buck in this case.

You have a session table (#Tally) with one record for each day and 30-years worth of days. The query selects back... 30-years worth of days. Since SQL Server has to do a full scan to get the data for each record in this case, I don't see adding the index giving you much benefit. Not with the schema and query from your example.

The N column is a nice natural key. I'm not sure it would hurt to add it, but I don't think you lose anything if you don't. However, if you do start to query a subset of values from the table (and I don't mean the entire set of records minus one or two), a clustered index will certainly add benefit.

Indexes are composed of pages. Pages can store a certain amount of data. You generally want to pack as much data with-in each page as possible. So, SQL Server doesn't have to scan too many pages to find your data. Think of each page like a drawer. If the drawer had 1 item in it, you'd need 500 drawers to store 500 items. If you wanted to find 20-items, you have to open 20-drawers. If each drawer had 100-items, you'd at most have to open at most 5-drawers and at least 1-drawer. Saying `FILLFACTOR equals 100` means you're not leaving any space in the page (drawer); you're filling it up completely. For fields where the data increments, using a fillfactor of 100 is a general best practice because you're never adding data in the middle of the index only adding it to the end. So, you don't need space in your index's existing pages for new data.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would take a different approach to creating a tally table. I keep this as a view on my systems. It is lightning fast and you never have to worry about storage. This is a technique I learned from Jeff Moden who learned about it from Itzik Ben-Gan. You can extend this to have more rows if you need more than 10,000 quite easily.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Answer (score 2):

Eray,

To keep things simple, the FILLFACTOR property tells SQL Server what percentage of the pages (that make up the index) are filled with data. If this is a table that will never change (the index need not be rebuilt); it makes sense to have this value set to 100 as any value less than 100 would reduce the capacity (though to a minor degree) of the amount of data that could be stored on each data page.

From MS's mouth; they refer to this being important when "future growth to an index is likely":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-2017

For more information please consult: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/